# Can one kern math font euler.otf using lualatex and fontspec?

Tags: math-mode, luatex, fontspec, kerning

I am at it again... :)

Using the http://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf/blob/master/euler.otf font, can one kern distance between T and P with Lualatex?

Clearly, my attempt does not work...

Could it perhaps be that the used glyphs are not called T and P?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mykern.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
feature kern {
    pos T P 200;
} kern;
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=upright,FeatureFile=mykern.fea]{euler.otf}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$TP$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe it is connected with this issue: http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2013-December/004688.html ?

Answer (score 4):

Not a full answer, but too long for a comment and I hope this is a useful start.

The `lualatex` version of `unicode-math` loads maths fonts with `Renderer=Basic` and so turns off such features.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mykern.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
feature kern {
    pos T P 200;
} kern;
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=upright,FeatureFile=mykern.fea]{euler.otf}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\fontspec[FeatureFile=mykern.fea]{euler.otf}
TP

\fontspec[Renderer=Basic,FeatureFile=mykern.fea]{euler.otf}
TP

$TP$

\end{document}
```

You should also note that in maths the font is loaded with `Script=Math`.

Comment: Makes me wonder if this `Renderer=Basic` for math is really needed or whether it could be turned of in order for me to get what I want...